# Unable to run Openstack-installer Error

Tags: 15.10, maas, openstack, openstack-autopilot

I'm trying to run the `sudo openstack-install` command, after installing `sudo apt-get install openstack`.

It gives me error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/openstack-install", line 279, in <module>
    ev = EventLoop(ui, cfg, logger)
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/ev.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.loop = self._build_loop()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/ev.py", line 66, in _build_loop
    event_loop=urwid.AsyncioEventLoop(loop=evl), **additional_opts)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'AsyncioEventLoop'
```

Trying to install openstack with the new Autopilot feature and MAAS, this code is run on the MAAS Server. (Ubuntu 15.10)

Output from .cloud-install/commands.log

```
[INFO: 01-05 14:52:22, openstack-install:204] Starting OpenStack Installer v0.99.24
[INFO: 01-05 14:52:22, openstack-install:205] Start command: ['/usr/bin/openstack-install']
[INFO: 01-05 14:52:22, openstack-install:216] Creating juju directories: /home/stian/.cloud-install/juju
[INFO: 01-05 14:52:22, openstack-install:269] Running Kilo release
[ERROR: 01-05 14:52:22, ev.py:143] Exception in ev.run():
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/ev.py", line 141, in run
    self.loop.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 274, in run
    self.screen.run_wrapper(self._run)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/raw_display.py", line 268, in run_wrapper
    return fn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 314, in _run
    self.draw_screen()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 566, in draw_screen
    self.screen.draw_screen(self.screen_size, canvas)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/raw_display.py", line 770, in draw_screen
    self._term_output_file.write(l)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-70: ordinal not in range(128)
[INFO: 01-05 14:52:22, utils.py:85] Cleanup, saving latest config object.
```

I am follow this official guide: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-openstack-with-autopilot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a complete reinstall, and everything works. I think it might be I didnt apt-get update with the new repositories added.

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this issue with the openstack-installer, but have a slightly newer version:

```
dpkg -l|grep openstack

ii  openstack                            0.99.27-0~1501~stable1~ubuntu15.10.1 all          Ubuntu Openstack Installer
```

It turns out that the version of urwid that is already installed is 1.2.1, and that does not have AsyncioEventLoop. The easiest solution is to upgrade urwid, currently at 1.3.1:

```
sudo pip3 install urwid --upgrade
```

You may need to install python3-pip to run the above command:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```